# Using surrogate keys in linking table in Access - how to show "friendly" key as well

Tags: sql, ms-access, many-to-many, ms-access-2010

I am migrating a horrific database from Lotus Approach '97 to MS Access 2010. This is the first time I have used access, however I am familiar with SQL.

I have a table of **Events**, and a table of **Clients**. These Clients are actually either **Individuals** or **Companies**. There is a joining table called **ClientEvents** which links the surrogate primary key of the Event to that of the Client. (i.e. There is a many to many relationship between Events and Clients).

My problem is that whenever I try to display the ClientEvents table for a particular Event, the result is simply a list of surrogate keys. This is of no use to my client who does not recognise these surrogate keys, however as soon as I try to do a multi-join or a subquery to select the name of the individual/comapny from the relevant table, the query/form is not updateable.

Presumably this problem is very common, as Surrogate keys must regularly be displayed next to recognisable fields from child tables?

I have tried using a DLookup in a continuous form but this is horrifically slow. Surely this kind of design is common in access? Or am I trying to be too clever implementing a proper relational design. Is access truly capable of such designs?

Comment: Does the design view of **ClientEvents** show the little key symbol next to its `ClientID` and its `EventID` columns?

Comment: Here's the design of Client Events: http://stockchat.eu/store/ClientEvents.jpg

Comment: Another thought, perhaps the issue here is the fact that the relationship between Individuals/Companies and Clients can be defined as "is a", and as a result I have a 1-1 relationship where the primary key of both individuals and companies is a foreign key to the [Client ID] AutoNumber in Clients. I don't think access likes this one bit...

Comment: That is the issue.  To make it updateable, you'll either need to dump it into a new table with the appropriate structure and query off that or figure up some `Dlookup` voodoo.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a subform (continuous or otherwise) with a ComboBox.  If you're making a form for you client, make a subform with a master-child relationship on ClientID.  In the subform add a combobox with a ControlSource of a query on your Events table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EventID, EventName FROM EVENTS
```

Then on the ComboBox properties, make the Column count = 2, the column widths = 0";1" (this will make the EventID *invisible* and the EventName be 1 inch wide).

The ComboBoxes in your subform **SHOULD** be updateable.  That should get you started.

Comment: Does this show all events for a given Client? I was wanting to do it the other way round- for a given Event, show all Clients (i.e. all individuals & companies referenced by ClientEvents).

Comment: +1 for subforms. You can have a main form for Clients that has a subform to display their associated Events, and you can have a main form for Events that has a subform to display their associated Clients.

Comment: Can I have a subform which shows both Individuals and Companies or do I need a subform for each?

Comment: To have a subform for a given client, it would work just as well the other way around.  You'll of course need to change your query and the master-child relationship to match `Events.EventID` and `Events.EventName`.  You can have Individuals and Companies in one since they are in the same table.

Comment: I think you may be missing the problem I am having here; Clients have an ID, but the name of the client is stored in either the Individuals table OR the Companies table. So I cannot simply show the clients- I must join this with the Individuals AND Companies tables. The join of these tables always results in "This recordset not updateable", since it is a multiway join.

Comment: I see now.  That is frustrating.  You can't use a `UNION` statement in the Control Source on the two tables?  Is there not a ClientName in the Clients table?  What is the relationship and what are the keys between the Clients, Individuals, and Companies tables?